# React Date-picker Selecting a Range of days not working

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I would like to show a specific range of selected Dates from React Date-Picker. I have tried with their documentation site demo code. but this code is not working .what will be the solution? Below is my sample code,
`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { addDays, format } from 'date-fns';
import { DateRange, DayPicker } from 'react-day-picker';

const pastMonth = new Date();
const App = () => {
  const defaultSelected: DateRange = {
    from: pastMonth,
    to: addDays(pastMonth, 4)
  };
  const [range, setRange] = useState < DateRange | undefined > (defaultSelected);
  let footer = <p>Please pick the first day.</p>;
  if (range?.from) {
    if (!range.to) {
      footer = <p>{format(range.from, 'PPP')}</p>;
    } else if (range.to) {
      footer = (
        <p>
          {format(range.from, 'PPP')}–{format(range.to, 'PPP')}
        </p>
      );
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <DayPicker
        mode="range"
        defaultMonth={pastMonth}
        selected={range}
        footer={footer}
        onSelect={setRange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`

I have tried to react day picker documentation site Selecting a Range of days demo code and I would like to show and selete range of date based on `react: 18.2.0`

Comment: I copied your code and it works completely.
my react version is 18.2.0
what is your error?

Comment: under const defaultSelected  DateRange shows an error:
Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8010)

Comment: is your file a ts file or js file?

Comment: I have practiced in js file

Comment: oh these are ts codes,
i will convert it to js in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove all types from prev code for use  as js code.
try this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { addDays, format } from 'date-fns';
import {  DayPicker } from 'react-day-picker';

const pastMonth = new Date();
const App = () => {
  const defaultSelected = {
    from: pastMonth,
    to: addDays(pastMonth, 4)
  };
  const [range, setRange] = useState(defaultSelected);
  let footer = <p>Please pick the first day.</p>;
  if (range?.from) {
    if (!range.to) {
      footer = <p>{format(range.from, 'PPP')}</p>;
    } else if (range.to) {
      footer = (
        <p>
          {format(range.from, 'PPP')}–{format(range.to, 'PPP')}
        </p>
      );
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <DayPicker
        mode="range"
        defaultMonth={pastMonth}
        selected={range}
        footer={footer}
        onSelect={setRange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Now it's working and I have found my mistake